# Ejb3 not deploying on wildfly server

Tags: wildfly

1. I am trying to deploy my project on "Wildfly" server.
2. war file has been deployed easily .
3. but there is problem with EJB.

these are server logs:-

```
"10:47:51,513 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found CEI-GEO-EJB.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called CEI-GEO-EJB.jar.dodeploy
10:47:51,529 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "CEI-GEO-EJB.jar" (runtime-name: "CEI-GEO-EJB.jar")
10:47:51,607 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed to define class com.geo.service.GEODeleteServiceImpl in Module "deployment.CEI-GEO-EJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/geo/service/GEODeleteServiceImpl (Module "deployment.CEI-GEO-EJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/geo/service/GEODeleteService
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.geo.service.GEODeleteService from [Module "deployment.CEI-GEO-EJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 23 more

10:47:51,763 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."CEI-GEO-EJB.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."CEI-GEO-EJB.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "CEI-GEO-EJB.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/geo/service/GEODeleteServiceImpl (Module "deployment.CEI-GEO-EJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/geo/service/GEODeleteService
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.geo.service.GEODeleteService from [Module "deployment.CEI-GEO-EJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 23 more

10:47:51,841 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "CEI-GEO-EJB.jar")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"CEI-GEO-EJB.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"CEI-GEO-EJB.jar\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"CEI-GEO-EJB.jar\"
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/geo/service/GEODeleteServiceImpl (Module \"deployment.CEI-GEO-EJB.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/geo/service/GEODeleteService
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.geo.service.GEODeleteService from [Module \"deployment.CEI-GEO-EJB.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
10:47:51,965 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "CEI-GEO-EJB.jar" (runtime-name : "CEI-GEO-EJB.jar")
10:47:51,965 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."CEI-GEO-EJB.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."CEI-GEO-EJB.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "CEI-GEO-EJB.jar""
```

Please help...................

Comment: Looks like you want to recompile your deployable.

Comment: sorry sir.... i did not understand what do you mean??

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a library jar

Comment: thanks sir for your reply........

Comment: the library which is missing here is present in the project, still it is showing that.. dont understand what to do.